# Writing shims for Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I need to fake `SHA1Cng.ComputeHash()` (and many other functions from various classes from `System.Security.Cryptography`).

I created the test project, referenced the main project in it, generated fakes for it, I also generated fakes for `System` which gave me `mscorlib.fakes` (where Cryptograhy is). I added the following lines:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Remove FullName="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple"/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.Security.Cryptography"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

I get plenty of errors for some reason:

> 'CryptoStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments (..\Debug\Fakes\m\f.csproj)
>
> 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments (..\Debug\Fakes\m\f.csproj)
>
> ...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: SHA1Cng is in System.Core.dll, not mscorlib. If that helps.

Comment: I get the same errors: 'CryptoStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 argument and 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments. I am not faking these, I just wanted to add a fake for my own class, but cant get past these fakes errors in my unit test project. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you remove the <ShimGeneration> section?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reverse out the Fakes file and only include what we needed. Something like the following:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.IO.FileSystemInfo"/>
    <Add FullName="System.IO.Path"/>
    <Add FullName="System.DateTime!" />
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

A bit of trial and error unfortunately. We'll be abandoning MS Fakes as soon as possible. Seems Microsoft has already abandoned it.